# Implementing search in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a textbox where user types the string he needs to search. If the user enters only a single word string, then I am able to retrieve the correct data from database but if the user enters a multi-word string then my code fails.

I am using EntityFramework to get the data.

Here is my code to get the data using a single word string.

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(string search)
{
   var j = objCon.Mobiles.Where(oh => oh.MobileName.Contains(search) || oh.Description.Contains(search));
   List<Mobiles> prod = new List<Mobiles>();
   foreach (var p in j)
   {
       Mobiles Mob = new Mobiles();
       Mob.Description = p.Description;
       Mob.ImgUrl = p.Url;
       Mob.MobileName = p.MobileName;
       Mob.Price = Convert.ToString(p.Price);
       Mob.SlNo = p.SlNo;
       prod.Add(Mob);
   }

   return View("~/Views/Product/Index.cshtml", prod);
}
```

I tried breaking the string into single word using split but could not get the correct data.

```
string str = null;
string[] strArr = null;
int count = 0;
str = //UserInput;
char[] splitchar = { ' ' };
strArr = str.Split(splitchar);
```

Comment: Can you show the value you are inputting and how it is represented in `objCon.Mobiles`

Comment: Can you share the data from search, mobile and description like an example.

Comment: For example Single word string "Nokia",

Comment: Multi word string "Nokia Mobile Phones"

Comment: @RandomCoder in objCon.Mobiles i'm looking into 2 columns the mobile name and the mobile description Mobile name example "Microsoft Lumia 640 XL LTE Dual SIM", Description example "Nokia Stereo Headset WH-108, Battery, Handset, User Guide, Charger".

Comment: So for the case when input is  "Nokia Mobile Phones" nothing is matched according to your example

Comment: @demo Exactly..

Comment: Then how your code fails?

Comment: @demo I did not mean to say that my codes gives me an error, but it does not retuen any value.

Comment: The Contains() method in C# is case sensitive are you typing exactly as it appears in your `objCon.Mobiles`

Comment: Then 1 more time: your input string is "Nokia Mobile Phones", while Mobile name example "Microsoft Lumia 640 XL LTE Dual SIM", Description example "Nokia Stereo Headset WH-108, Battery, Handset, User Guide, Charger"... so there is no exact match for your input search string

Comment: @demo There is not exact match that is the reason i tried splitting the string an search individual word. But i the this error  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.
`

Comment: @RandomCoder i tried with multiple strings and tried to macth the case from the database

Comment: @demo i get that exception at the foreach loop.      My database column datatype is nvarchar(max).

Comment: Is it this place that throws error : `Convert.ToString(p.Price)` ? If so, just use `p.Price.ToString()`

Comment: Can you try `foreach (var p in j.ToList())`. Can you debug the code and tell us, what error ur getting and in which line? And also, what the value in search

Comment: @demo  ` foreach (var p in j)` i get the exception here

Comment: Can u try adding the .ToList().

Comment: @demo i tried .ToList() again the same error

Comment: Whats the value in search ? Can you pls try by hard coding the search as "Nokia" inside the where clause and see whether results are coming from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = null;
        string[] strArr = null;
        int count = 0;
        str = search;
        char[] splitchar = { ' ' };
        strArr = str.Split(splitchar);
        for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
        {
            string i = strArr[count];
            var j = objCon.Mobiles.Where(oh => oh.MobileName.Contains(i) || oh.Description.Contains(i));
            //MessageBox.Show(strArr[count]); 
            foreach (var p in j)
            {
                Mobiles Mob = new Mobiles();
                Mob.Description = p.Description;
                Mob.ImgUrl = p.Url;
                Mob.MobileName = p.MobileName;
                Mob.Price = Convert.ToString(p.Price);
                Mob.SlNo = p.SlNo;
                prod.Add(Mob);
            }
        }
```

as I help you fix the problem - this is the final code

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194241/helping-hand

enter the room so I can help you

Comment: @ShubhamSingh if you're happy please make this as the answer! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I Wrote an Example to Solve your Problem. Hope That You will Be Benefited From The Code.

First Create Mobile Class:

```
 public class Mobile
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

Next Create Extension method To Check If there is Value:

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string haystack, params string[] needles)
        {
            foreach (var needle in needles)
            {
                if (haystack.Contains(needle))    
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Finally Create Main Body Along with Test Data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Mobile> mobiles = new List<Mobile>
            {
                new Mobile{Id = 1,Name = "samsung galaxy s3",Description = "model"},
                new Mobile{Id = 2,Name = "nokia N67",Description = "nokia n96 time"},
                new Mobile{Id = 3,Name = "iphone 5s",Description = "test"},
                new Mobile{Id = 4,Name = "samsung galaxy packet",Description = "this time"},
                new Mobile{Id = 5,Name = "iphone ipad",Description = "now"},
                new Mobile{Id = 6,Name = "glx c5",Description = "time"},
            };

            string[] search = "galaxy time 5s".Split(' ');

            var result = mobiles.Where(c => c.Name.ContainsAny(search) ||
                                            c.Description.ContainsAny(search)).ToList();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Id + "-" + item.Name + "-" + item.Description);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I found a way to do it but I'll try your way and see which one's better